# Open graph data not visible in iFramely or WhatsApp despite working on Facebook

Tags: meta-tags, meta-description, open-graph-protocol

I have [this](http://yumyumofficial.xyz) self-hosted WordPress site. I have added all the needed meta tags. They do come up on Facebook open graph debugger and show up when sharing links.

They don't work anywhere else. iFramely debugger cannot find any meta tags, also sharing on WhatsApp or telegram doesn't show any preview.

What do I need to do to get all these other places to recognize my OG data?

Comment: *But, they don't work anywhere else.* Can you give examples of where you are expecting the OG code to work? As far as I know, these are only used on Facebook.

Comment: @closetnoc In WhatsApp, for example.

Comment: I thought this was an important question to ask. I will let our experts answer. I know next to nothing on the matter. Thanks for your response! It gives people a target to shoot for. Cheers!!